# How to return the name of a variable stored at a particular memory address in C++

Tags: c++, windows, variables, memory-address

first time posting here after having so many of my Google results come up from this wonderful site.

Basically, I'd like to find the name of the variable stored at a particular memory address. I have a memory editing application I wrote that edits a single value, the problem being that every time the application holding this value is patched, I have to hardcode in the new memory address into my application, and recompile, which takes so much time to upkeep that its almost not worthwhile to do.

What I'd like to do is grab the name of the variable stored at a certain memory address, that way I can then find its address at runtime and use that as the memory address to edit.

This is all being written in C++.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Well I've decided I'd like to stream the data from a .txt file, but I'm not sure how to convert the string into an LPVOID for use as the memory address in WriteProcessMemory(). This is what I've tried:

```
    string fileContents;

    ifstream memFile("mem_address.txt");
        getline(memFile, fileContents);
    memFile.close();

    LPVOID memAddress = (LPVOID)fileContents.c_str();

    //Lots of code..

    WriteProcessMemory(WindowsProcessHandle, memAddress, &BytesToBeWrote, sizeof(BytesToBeWrote), &NumBytesWrote);
```

The code is all correct in terms of syntax, it compiles and runs, but the WriteProcessMemory errors and I can only imagine it has to do with my faulty LPVOID variable. I apologize if extending the use of my question is against the rules, I'll remove my edit if it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile and generate a so called `map` file. This can be done easily with Visual-C++ (`/MAP` linker option). There you'll see the symbols (functions, ...) with their starting address. Using this map file (Caution: has to be updated each time you recompile) you can match the addresses to names.

This is actually not so easy because the addresses are relative to the preferred load address, and probably will (randomization) be different from the actual load address.

Some old hints on retrieving the right address can be found here: http://home.hiwaay.net/~georgech/WhitePapers/MapFiles/MapFiles.htm

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers, under my circumstances it'd appear that I won't be able to accomplish exactly what I had in mind, but at least I've got enough closure on the subject to prevent me from wasting even more time contemplating how I could do this.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the names of variables are not kept around when the program is compiled. If you are in control of the compilation process, you can usually configure the linker and compiler to produce a map-file listing the locations in memory of all global variables. However, if this is the case, you can probably acheive your goals more easily by not using direct memory accesses, but rather creating a proper command protocol that your external program can call into.

If you do not have control of the compilation process of the other program, you're probably out of luck, unless the program shipped with a map file or debugging symbols, either of which can be used to derive the names of variables from their addresses.

Note that for stack variables, deriving their names will require full debugging symbols and is a very non-trivial process. Heap variables have no names, so you will have no luck there, naturally. Further, as mentioned in @jdehaan's answer, map files can be a bit tricky to work with in the best of times. All in all, it's best to have a proper control protocol you can use to avoid any dependence on the contents of the other program's memory at all.

Finally, if you have no control over the other program, then I would recommend putting the variable location into a separate datafile. This way you would no longer need to recompile each time, and could even support multiple versions of the program being poked at. You could also have some kind of auto-update service pulling new versions of this datafile from a server of yours if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually own the application in question, there is no standard way to do this. If you do own the application, you can follow @jdehaan answer.

In any case, instead of hardcoding the memory address into your application, why not host a simple feed somewhere that you can update at any time with the memory address you need to change for each version of the target application? This way, instead of recompiling your app every time, you can just update that feed when you need to be able to manipulate a new version.

Comment: I can't believe I never thought of this! I'll definitely look into parsing a feed or text file as a solution to this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly do this; variable names do not actually exist in the compiled binary. You *might* be able to do that if the program was written, in say, Java or C#, which do store information about variables in the compiled binary.

Further, this wouldn't in general be possible, because it's always possible that the most up to date copy of a value inside the target program is located inside of a CPU register rather than in memory. This is more likely if the program in question is compiled in release mode, with optimizations turned on.

If you can ensure the target program is compiled in debug mode you should be able to use the debugging symbols emitted by the compiler (the .pdb file) in order to map addresses to variables, but in that case you would need to launch the target process as if it were being debugged -- the plain Read Process Memory and Write Process Memory methods would not work.

Finally, your question ignores a very important consideration -- there need not be a variable corresponding to a particular address even if such information is stored.

Comment: `Write/ReadProcessMemory()` can certainly be used with debugging symbols without needing to launch the app in a specific way. How else would VC++ attach to running processes? Of course, nobody ever said it was _easy_ to interpret debugging symbols... :)

Comment: @bdonlan: I'm assuming local variables. You would have to stop program execution to see when these go into and out of scope. That requires launching the target process under a debugger.

Comment: Or attaching a debugger after the fact, but indeed, you'd need to stop execution to get a stable read on whether the local variable exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source to the app in question and optimal memory usage is not a concern, then you can declare the interesting variables inside a debugging-friendly structure similar to:

```
typedef struct {
    const char head_tag[15] = "VARIABLE_START";
          char var_name[32];
          int  value;
    const char tail_tag[13] = "VARIABLE_END";
} debuggable_int;
```

Now, your app should be able to search through the memory space for the program and look for the head and tail tags.  Once it locates one of your debuggable variables, it can use the `var_name` and `value` members to identify and modify it.

If you are going to go to this length, however, you'd probably be better off building with debugging symbols enabled and using a regular debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Billy O'Neal started to head in the right direction, but didn't (IMO) quite get to the real target. Assuming your target is Windows, a much simpler way would be to use the Windows Symbol handler functions, particularly `SymFromName`, which will let you supply the symbol's name, and it will return (among other things) the address for that symbol.

Of course, to do any of this you *will* have to run under an account that's allowed to do debugging. At least for global variables, however, you don't necessarily have to stop the target process to find symbols, addresses, etc. In fact, it works just fine for a process to use these on itself, if it so chooses (quite a few of my early experiments getting to know these functions did exactly that). Here's a bit of demo code I wrote years ago that gives at least a general idea (though it's old enough that it uses `SymGetSymbolFromName`, which is a couple of generations behind `SymFromName`). Compile it with debugging information and stand back -- it produces quite a lot of output.

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define DBGHELP_TRANSLATE_TCHAR
#include <windows.h>
#include <imagehlp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iomanip>
#pragma comment(lib, "dbghelp.lib")

int y;

int junk() {
    return 0;
}

struct XXX { 
    int a;
    int b;
} xxx;

BOOL CALLBACK 
sym_handler(wchar_t const *name, ULONG_PTR address, ULONG size, void *) {
    if (name[0] != L'_')
        std::wcout << std::setw(40) << name 
            << std::setw(15) << std::hex << address 
            << std::setw(10) << std::dec << size << L"\n";
    return TRUE;
}

int 
main() {
    char const *names[] = { "y", "xxx"};

    IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL info;

    SymInitializeW(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, TRUE);

    SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_UNDNAME);

    SymEnumerateSymbolsW(GetCurrentProcess(), 
        (ULONG64)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        sym_handler,
        NULL);

    info.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL);

    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]); i++) {
        if ( !SymGetSymFromName(GetCurrentProcess(), names[i], &info)) {
            std::wcerr << L"Couldn't find symbol 'y'";
            return 1;
        }

        std::wcout << names[i] << L" is at: " << std::hex << info.Address << L"\n";
    }

    SymCleanup(GetCurrentProcess());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably WinDbg's "!ln" command is implemented using something similar internally

Comment: @chubsdad: Yes, I'd guess it is (with the obvious difference that it passes some *other* process instead of `GetCurrentProcess()` as I have above...)

Answer (score 0):

WinDBG has a particularly useful command

> ln

[here](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#10_modules)

Given a memory location, it will give the name of the symbol at that location. With right debug information, it is a debugger's (I mean person doing debugging :)) boon!.

Here is a sample output on my system (XP SP3)

> 0:000> ln 7c90e514 (7c90e514)
>   ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet   | 
>   (7c90e520)   ntdll!KiIntSystemCall
>   Exact matches:
>       ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet ()